# Custom word list generation for a specific web domain

Tags: passwords, password-cracking

I am looking for a tool that generates a set of word lists based on the words it finds on the pages of a particular web domain. [This](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/35583/password-list-generation) question has an answer that generates permuted word lists starting from existing ones. Other tools such **crunch** in backtrack/kali has a number of modes of generation but does not take into account an existing word list.

How can I generate passwords based on words on the web domain?

Comment: Do you mean you would like to scrape the web site and generate a list of words from its content?

Comment: Yes, based on some criteria for example word frequency.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**A Python solution**

You can use [Scrapy](http://scrapy.org/) which will make most of the work for you. You then would just need to use [`Counter()`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) to get the top words (if looking for frequency counts).

You could also use a more low-level approach with [Beautiful Soup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) to get the top 5 words:

```
# coding=utf-8
import requests
import collections
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

thesite = requests.get("http://www.lemonde.fr").text

soup = BeautifulSoup(thesite, 'html.parser')
thewords = soup.get_text().split()

print(collections.Counter(thewords).most_common(5))
```

Since the output is

```
[('de', 223), ('la', 154), (':', 123), ('{', 115), ('à', 84)]
```

you could look at setting a minimal length of a "word" (3 perhaps?)

**UPDATE**: the code for a sorted list of most common words with 3 or more letters

```
# coding=utf-8
import requests
import collections
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import operator

thesite = requests.get("http://www.lemonde.fr").text

soup = BeautifulSoup(thesite, 'html.parser')
thewords = soup.get_text().split()

# keep only words over 3 chars

thewords = {w: f for  w, f in collections.Counter(thewords).items() if len(w) > 3}
topwords = sorted(thewords.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(1), reverse=True)

print(topwords)
```

Answer (score 2):

How about using a tool called [CeWL - Custom Word List generator](https://digi.ninja/projects/cewl.php)?

> CeWL is a ruby app which spiders a given url to a specified depth,
>   optionally following external links, and returns a list of words which
>   can then be used for password crackers such as John the Ripper.